# mapView addAnnotation not always working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, xcode5

I have a weird bug with annotations not always being added to my mapview, my code that adds annotations is:

```
- (void)plotVehicles {

NSMutableArray *currentVehicles = [[MyApplication getInstance] currentVehicles];

for (Vehicle * veh in currentVehicles) {
    VehiclePin * vehiclePin = [[VehiclePin alloc] initWithVehicle:veh];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:vehiclePin];
    [self.vehiclePins addObject:vehiclePin];
    NSLog(@"current ann %i %@ %@",self.mapView.annotations.count,vehiclePin,self.mapView.annotations);
}
NSLog(@"annotations added %i/%i",self.mapView.annotations.count,self.vehiclePins.count);
}
```

I am adding annotations to the `mapView` and to `vehiclePins` and have 2 logs, the first one (inside the loop) shows which annotations is going to be added and the current state of the mapview.annotations.  The result of this log is:

```
current ann 1 <VehiclePin: 0x1573c470> (
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573c470>"
)

current ann 2 <VehiclePin: 0x9e7f490> (
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573c470>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x9e7f490>"
)
 current ann 2 <VehiclePin: 0x9e7f430> (
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573c470>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x9e7f490>"
)
current ann 3 <VehiclePin: 0x1573f730> (
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573c470>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x9e7f490>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573f730>"
)
 current ann 3 <VehiclePin: 0x1573f870> (
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573c470>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x9e7f490>",
    "<VehiclePin: 0x1573f730>"
)
...
```

For a total of 31 annotations, but the array never changes after that point (3 elements) and the not so surprising result of the second log is:

```
annotations added 3/31
```

I am currently using Xcode 5, didn't have the problem when using xcode 4.6

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Also I've checked with `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` and they are valid, and different coordinates.

Comment: Is removeAnnotation called anywhere in the app?

Comment: No, I removed almost any other interaction with the map to try to isolate the problem, turned out to being solved by a different way. I wrote an answer about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. What I did was that uninstalled the app and cleaned the build, compiled again and started working. Second time this kind of problem happens to me with XCode 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you are trying to add the **same** annotation multiple times to the map and to the `vehiclePins` array.
For the array, this is no problem, since an array can store the same object multiple times. But this is not true for an annotation: Each annotation object is stored only once.